# Input and button inline

Tags: html, css, button, input

Is there a multi-browser way to inline input and button? See http://jsfiddle.net/wf592/. Input appears below button. Simple margin doesn't help:

```
<div>
<input type="text" style="margin-top:-50px;" /><button style="height:25px; width:20px"  />
</div>
```

This error showed up when I used jQueryUI calendar: calendar button is automatically inserted after the input tag. So I don't want to change markup with more divs.

Comment: The elements are inline in the jsfiddle, as expected. You should describe, in the question, what is wrong with the presentation. It probably has to do with vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf592/2/)

Add:

```
input, button{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

More on `vertical-align` [from MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.

Comment: You made a typo, should be input, not inut. But other than that, works like a magic! Thank you!